# Find Email that meets the condition inside special cells with formula

Tags: excel, email, excel-formula, vba

I am working on a tracker that has a function of emailing people who didn't meet a criteria. I have NAMES reflected in Row 19 (`H19:AE19` to be specific; each cell column reflects 1 name); emails in Row 18 relative to the respective name; and conditions to be met in Row 20 (send email if blank; move to next if populated).

Additional information: each of these details have formulas embedded. It changes whenever a certain drop down is changed.

And so, the code is below and I can't seem to get it work:

```
Sub Test1()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error GoTo cleanup


For Each cell In Rows(18).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Value Like "?*@ntrs.com" And _
    LCase(cell.Offset(2).Value) = "" Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Reminder"
            .Body = "Dear " & cell.Offset(1).Value _
                  & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "Please contact us to discuss bringing " & _
                    "your account up to date"
            .Display
            .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell
cleanup:
Set OutApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Please tell us where your code does not work and how it fails.

Comment: @DavidG Hi David! Thank you for your reply. Got it working now as suggested by A.S.H.

Comment: Title was not very explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, you say

> each of these details have formulas embedded

If the email addresses in row 18 have formulas, this line wont catch them:

> `For Each cell In Rows(18).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`

Changing it to the following may solve the problem, and it is preferable in any case because you later check the string against the email pattern:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(18).Cells
```

Better even, specify your sheet that has those data, i.e. if its name is "myEmails"; make it

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("myEmails").UsedRange.Rows(18).Cells
```

Comment: Wow! It works! Thank you very much! Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @MarkSy you are welcome. Glad it helped. Please when an answer solves your problem think of "accepting" it by clicking the grey checkmark on the topleft of the answer, turning it into green :)